# Why does copying a column of a cv::Mat into a vector fail?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, stl

Consider the following code sample. Why does the line marked below trigger a breakpoint/exception at runtime?

```
int main() {
    Mat m1 = Mat::zeros(10, 1, CV_32FC1);
    Mat m2 = Mat::zeros(10, 3, CV_32FC1);

    vector<float> v1(m1); // works
    Mat m2sub = m2.col(0);
    Mat m2subClone = m2.col(0).clone();
    vector<float> v2(m2subClone); // works
    vector<float> v3(m2sub); // doesn't work
return 0;
}
```

It seems strange as what's being called is in mat.hpp:

```
template<typename _Tp> inline Mat::operator std::vector<_Tp>() const {
    std::vector<_Tp> v;
    copyTo(v);
    return v; // <- breaks here
}
```

and copyTo seems to memcpy the data.

It doesn't give a error message but I see in the stack trace that it breaks at the return statement, and then somewhere deep into an 'operator new' and 'ntdll.dll!RtlpAllocateHeap()'.

Strangely, in my full code, it breaks at a slightly different place: inside copyTo(v) at the memcpy, and throws a 'Access violation writing location 0x0000000001F43D4C.'. My full code looks exactly like the one above, but the matrices are bigger.

Edit: If in above example, I change the matrices to

```
    Mat m1 = Mat::zeros(5900, 1, CV_32FC1);
    Mat m2 = Mat::zeros(5900, 3, CV_32FC1);
```

the snippet fails at the same place than my full code, with the access violation error.

I have over 2GB RAM free, and the app is compiled as a 64-bit app, so it shouldn't be an 'out of memory' issue (?)

Comment: It appears there is some difference in behavior depending on which platform you are using (See the comments under Luiz's answer). What compiler and version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: @Aurelius I'm using VS2012, 64bit, OpenCV is from Git and a few months old (March-July something. Git shows 2.4.4/2.4.5, however the dll's have the suffix 249. I could maybe dig deeper and find out if relevant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand deeply the OpenCV Mat class, but I guess there is something shared by the columns in the matrices, so memcopying it might not be a good idea. Checking the OpenCV documentation of the Mat::row method ([here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat%20Mat%3a%3arow%28int%20y%29%20const), the Mat::col method has the same argument about a "shared header"), there is a note indicating that the following **is not a good idea**:

```
Mat A;
...
A.row(i) = A.row(j); // will not work
```

and that you should use the following instead:

```
A.row(j).copyTo(A.row(i));
```

So, perhaps in your code you should have used this:

```
vector<float> v3;
m2sub.copyTo(v3);
```

Comment: This does not address the OP's problem. As stated in the question, `copyTo()` is being called exactly in the way you suggest within the conversion.

Comment: Though, I just tested the code here (MSVC 10, Windows 7, 32bit binary) and it does not break with m2sub.copyTo(v3); (even though it breaks with vector<float> v3(m2sub);).

Comment: My point was that perhaps the problem is related to double deletion or something like it, since OpenCV implements reference counting (and std vector does not). At this page there is some discussion about the need of using clone (the one used in m2subClone) and copyTo: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html

Comment: That is actually an interesting observation. Both versions break for me using Xcode and OpenCV 2.4.5. Oddly, the OP's code with only 10 elements doesn't break for me.

Comment: @LuizVieira: So m2sub.copyTo(v3) works, and vector<float> v3(m2sub); breaks? Is that for 10 elements or also for 5900?

Comment: @Aurelius: For you everything without clone breaks for 5900 elements, and both work for 10 elements? 
That sounds like something odd is going on?
Does it break for you both on the return statement or inside the copyTo?

Comment: @Ela782: Yes, just as you said. I tested with only 10 elements. Later today I will test it again with 5900 to see if there are any differences.

Comment: I just confirmed in here: for 5900 elements, the code breaks in both "m2sub.copyTo(v3)" and "vector<float> v3(m2sub)" approaches...

Comment: The code breaks at the memcpy function. I read somewhere in the OpenCV documentation (couldn't find it again) that the internal pointer is handled in a row-based fashion. So, since the col method just reteurns a reference, memcopying is messing things up. I did a quick test and changed to Mat m2 = Mat::zeros(5900, 300, CV_32FC1); Also, I changed every call to col to a call to row. The code works fine. So, to me, the problem is due to the fact that subparts are not cloned and the column pointer is not sequential (more info here http://itanveer.com/2012/05/18/linear-algebra-in-opencv-post2/)